# AWS EC2 - block access for HTTP request via static IP

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, bitnami

I’ve got an EC2 instance with a couple of websites in the root folder (each website has it’s own folder).

/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/website1
/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/website2

I’ve created Virtual Hosts and pointed their respective domains to the instance’ elastic IP. Everything is working as expected when you try to access the websites through their domain names but I want to block access to these websites if someone is trying to access them via the elastic IP.

http://54.253.253.0/website1
http://54.253.253.0/website2

I prefer to block HTTP access through the IP all together, so visitors must type in the domain name to view access websites but I’m not sure how to do this.

Help will be much appreciated!

Comment: no website1 or website2 in the URL there. 
Typing 54.253.253.0 returns to the actual website...
if you still want to "block" request you might edit the virtual address setting in *httpd-vhosts.conf* using hostname

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this please add entry in virtual host. It will help you to block all access those are trying to open your site through public/local ip.

> ## Step 1 Add configuration in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost <localIPOfMachine>:80>
      DocumentRoot /home/errorfiles
</VirtualHost>
```

> ## Step2 Create display message (index.html)
>
> cd /home/errorfiles
>
> vim home/errorfiles/index.html

```
<html>
            <body>
                <h3> Access Denied! </h3>
            </body>
</html>
```

> service httpd reload

For demonstration purpose, I have restrict access through IP http://54.191.178.167/

User can access the site through domain only [www.apnok.com](http://www.apnok.com)